# For which $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ik(u+v)}f(u,v)dudv<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For example, is there a function $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the condition $\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}|f(u,v)g(u,v)|dudv<\infty$ implies $\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ik(u+v)}f(u,v)dudv<\infty$?

Comment: Instead of "${} < \infty$" it is better to write "converges" when something could have complex values.  Or even when it has real values but could diverge for some reason other than going to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t+s,-s) ds$, we reduce the question to the following one: when $$\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i k t} g(t) dt$$ is finite? Setting $h(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty g(t + 2 \pi k)$, we see that the summands in the above expression are simply the coefficients of the Fourier series of $h$. Thus, the question is: when the Fourier coefficients of a periodic function $h$ form a summable sequence. (I assume your question asks for absolute summability.)

As far as I know, there is no simple "if and only if" condition. It is clearly sufficient to assume that $h$ is sufficiently smooth, say: twice continuously differentiable (or differentiable, with $f'$ Hölder continuous). There is no sufficient condition of the form $\int_0^{2 \pi} |h(t) \phi(t)| dt < \infty$, unless $\phi$ is infinite almost everywhere (indeed: take $h$ to be any discontinuous function supported on the set $\{t : |\phi(t)| < M \}$ for some $M$; if the Fourier coefficients of $h$ were summable, $f$ would be a continuous function).

So the answer to you question is **no**: there is no such function $g(u,v)$.